# VPN connected and passing DPD keep-alive but no other traffic

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn

I have a connection to my work VPN up using Shrewsoft VPN client (IPSec, IKEv1).  It's connected and I can see NATT keepalive and DPD keepalive traffic going over, but I have no network connectivity at all.

Here is a sample of `tcpdump` output from my wifi adapter ("gateway" is the VPN gateway):

```
22:15:52.830866 IP MyComputer.lan.ipsec-nat-t > gateway.aaaa.bbbb.cccc.uk.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0x9e3cb62c,seq=0xfb), length 116
22:15:53.514843 IP MyComputer.lan.ipsec-nat-t > gateway.aaaa.bbbb.cccc.uk.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0x9e3cb62c,seq=0xfc), length 132
22:15:53.514892 IP MyComputer.lan.ipsec-nat-t > gateway.aaaa.bbbb.cccc.uk.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0x9e3cb62c,seq=0xfd), length 132
22:15:53.629797 IP MyComputer.lan.ipsec-nat-t > gateway.aaaa.bbbb.cccc.uk.ipsec-nat-t: isakmp-nat-keep-alive
22:15:53.703485 IP MyComputer.lan.ipsec-nat-t > gateway.aaaa.bbbb.cccc.uk.ipsec-nat-t: NONESP-encap: isakmp: phase 2/others I inf[E]
22:15:53.727050 IP gateway.aaaa.bbbb.cccc.uk.ipsec-nat-t > MyComputer.lan.ipsec-nat-t: NONESP-encap: isakmp: phase 2/others R inf[E]
22:15:54.282825 IP MyComputer.lan.ipsec-nat-t > gateway.aaaa.bbbb.cccc.uk.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0x9e3cb62c,seq=0xfe), length 116
22:15:54.282873 IP MyComputer.lan.ipsec-nat-t > gateway.aaaa.bbbb.cccc.uk.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0x9e3cb62c,seq=0xff), length 116
22:15:54.603844 IP MyComputer.lan.ipsec-nat-t > gateway.aaaa.bbbb.cccc.uk.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0x9e3cb62c,seq=0x100), length 132
22:15:54.603893 IP MyComputer.lan.ipsec-nat-t > gateway.aaaa.bbbb.cccc.uk.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0x9e3cb62c,seq=0x101), length 132
```

And here are the network interfaces with the VPN up:

```
me@MyComputer:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.214/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 34858sec preferred_lft 34858sec
    inet6 fe80::7c69:b283:3786:556/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: wwp0s20u4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP> mtu 1428 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: tap0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1380 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.246.46/32 brd 192.168.246.46 scope global tap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4caa:aaff:fe4a:d9b0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I *think* the routing table looks ok, but I am very vague about this (`**.**.**.**` is the IP of the VPN gateway):

```
me@MyComputer:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.246.66 dev tap0 proto static 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
**.**.**.** via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.214 metric 600
```

`tcpdump` on `tap0` shows only ARP requests.

I have set `rp-filter` to 0 for all the network adapters in case source validation was the cause, but it has not helped:

```
me@MyComputer:~$ sysctl -a | grep rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s25.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s25.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.tap0.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.tap0.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wlp3s0.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wlp3s0.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s20u4.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.wwp0s20u4.rp_filter = 0
```

While the VPN is up I get no response to any pings and DNS queries time out.  The same VPN works fine from a Windows 10 machine (different client) connected through the same router over the same internet connection.

Can anyone help where I could look next to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What does `ip route` tell you? Is there a `default` route pointing to the VPN?

Comment: yes, 18.04.  I've added the output of `ip route` to the question.  thanks